# Trickly null validation for SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, dbnull

```
"AND TT.[_TYPE] = CASE WHEN " + String.IsNullOrEmpty(lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem) ? 
 DBNull.Value} +  
" IS NULL THEN TT.[_TYPE] ELSE " + lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem + " END ";
```

Above is a pseudo aspect of my query.

I need to do a validation of listbox item for null and then set as DBNull.Value, which is to be passed into CASE WHEN within SQL Query.

Any better way to achieve this? I am getting tons of String to Bool, Null to String conversion errors...

Further, is there anyway to pass DBNull.Value as a Parameter across data access layer?

**EDIT: original query is in a Static class.**

```
    public static readonly string SqlGetItemsBy_Number_Capacity_Type =   
    "SELECT TT.[_NUMBER], " +
    "TT.[CAPACITY], " +
    "TT.[_TYPE], " +                  
    "TS.[SESSIONE] " +
    "FROM [ITEMS] AS TT, //some code
    "WHERE //some code
    "AND TT.[_TYPE] = CASE WHEN @Type IS NULL THEN TT.[_TYPE] ELSE @Type END";
```

If I run the same query in SQL Server, it works fine.

```
  SELECT //some code
  AND [_TYPE] = CASE WHEN NULL IS NULL THEN [_TYPE] ELSE @TYPE END
```

**Finally:** I decided to go with SQL Append and following to validate/set parameter.

```
    string paramAppend;
    var bld = lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem;

    if (bld != null)
    {
        paramAppend = "AND TT.[_TYPE] = " + lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
    else
        paramAppend = "";
```

Comment: Why aren't you using parameters? `@SelectedItem IS NULL OR TT.[_TYPE] = @SelectedItem`

Comment: a: SQL INJECTION!!! b: why do you need to do that in the TSQL? can't you just form the appropriate query based on whether there is a value, and keep the TSQL simple?

Comment: c: you have a malformed "conditional" operator; `a ? b` is not valid by itself; should be `a ? b : c`; not sure how you want us to interpret that, since it won't compile

Comment: @MarcGravell that's why I said it's *pseudo* query aspect. I am trying to feeding in `DBNull.Value` into the query. Sure it doesn't compile. ;) All my SQL queries are set in a Static class... in Data Access Layer

Comment: @bonCodigo but **why** are you trying to feed `DBNull.Value` into the query? in the case when no search-type is selected, what do you expect the TSQL to be?

Comment: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedItem", String.IsNullOrEmpty(lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem) ? (object) DBNull.Value : lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem);`

Comment: @ta.speot.is it *looks* like that actually represents a column name, in which case it can't be parameterized - it should, however, be white-listed

Comment: @MarcGravell If it's a column name that would make my comments pretty useless.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I must confess, it isn't entirely obvious in the context; I *hope* it is meant to be a column name, otherwise it makes very little sense

Comment: @MarcGravell Let us be confused together.

Comment: Let apart the validations... even this doesn't work... `"AND TT.[TABLE_TYPE] = CASE WHEN " + DBNull.Value +
" IS NULL THEN TT.[TABLE_TYPE] ELSE " + lstTableTypeSearch.SelectedItem + " END ";` Error says "Incorrect syntax near keyword IS" can't get any better...

Comment: @bonCodigo but what does that even to ask "when null is null` ? what are you trying to **do** ?

Comment: @bonCodigo but why are you trying to feed DBNull.Value into the query? in the case when no search-type is selected, what do you expect the TSQL to be? : All I need to do is validate my listbox for null or value. If null then feed that into the case when within SQL, so it will return all the data.

Comment: @bonCodigo if you want to return all the data: **don't add a filter in the first place**; don't add a "where null is null" filter - that is silly

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes it's silly, but if it's a stored proc and there's multiple filters and and you try to apply "don't add a filter in the first place" rule then you end up with dynamic SQL.

Comment: @MarcGravell, user may or may not select the type. So in that case, query should be able to handle that situation without raising an error. When user leaves type empty, query should return all values and otherwise return the values based on the filter (type). I guess ta.speot.is referring to what I am after. I have multiple filters, not just type...

Comment: @ta.speot.is if you are concatenating input like that, then **it isn't a stored proc**. In fact, if you are concatenating input like that, then *you're already doing dynamic SQL*

Comment: @MarcGravell *Above is a pseudo aspect of my query.* I have no idea what `pseudo aspect of my query` is meant to mean. OP has clarified he's not running a stored procedure, and his query appears static.

Comment: @ta.speot.is as soon as you're concatenating and branching: it isn't static

Comment: @MarcGravell I know what you're saying but perhaps I wasn't clear enough. `pseudo aspect of my query` with some pseudo-C# and SQL smushed together doesn't tell me enough information about the context any more than "here's a psuedo aspect of what I want" drawn on a whiteboard. For all I know OP only knows how to represent some concepts with C# and SQL with others.

Comment: @MarcGravell `as soon as you're concatenating and branching: it isn't static`, does this mean, taking the approach we discuss here will breach the current class design pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `lstTypeSearch` here represents a column name (hence parameterization: not an option), so the first thing I'd say is: make sure you white-list that. Rather than trying to do everything in one go, separate the two cases:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem))
{
    // nothing to check?
}
else
{
    CheckValidColumn(lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem); // throws if white-list fails
    sql.Append(" AND TT.[_TYPE] = [") // should probably add table alias
       .Append(lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem)
       .Append("]");
}
```

If I have misunderstood, and this isn't a column, then just parameterize:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem))
{
    // no restriction?
}
else
{
    sql.Append(" AND TT.[_TYPE] = @type");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("type", lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem);
}
// ...
cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();
```

Comment: +1 `sql.Append` Intelligently using `StringBuilder` for string building.

Comment: @ta.speot.is almost like I've done this once or twice before ;p

Comment: Now this makes all the sense... Glad you have second option. Yes ListBox isn't a column. So I will go with SQL Append as shown in second solution.

Comment: Minor point, I'm pretty sure ADO.NET will want `AddWithValue("type"` to be `AddWithValue("@type"`

Comment: @ta.speot.is actually, no it won't; it is perfectly happy with either. I generally exclude the prefix, as I work on libs etc that might be targeting different database implementations

Comment: So today my question made you guys learn... it's a shame to be on a down vote.. .not that I care ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should work with parameters, unless want to be exposed to potential sql injection threats.

Second, if you are building the sql dynamically in the code, a better approach would be to add the sql condition only if lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem is not an empty string or null. something like that:

```
sSql = "your sql query";
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem)) {
    sSql += "TT.[_TYPE] = '" + lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem + "'";
}
sSql += ";"
```

btw, what if the SelectedItem has a string that only contains white spaces? consider replacing the String.IsNullOrEmpty to String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace.

Answer (score 2):

> If null then feed that into the case when within SQL, so it will return all the data.

I'm interpreting this to mean that if there's no value specified then return all the rows, otherwise filter by that value.

I'm assuming `lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem` is your value and it's a `string`. If not, cast it or dig out the string value.

```
command.CommandText =
    "SELECT * FROM TT WHERE @SelectedItem IS NULL OR TT.[_TYPE] = @SelectedItem";

var selectedItem = (string) lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedItem",
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedItem) ? (object) DBNull.Value : selectedItem);

using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Get the `.Value` or `.Text` of the `SelectedItem`.

Comment: @Kaf [If it's a WinForms `ListBox` there is no `Value` or `Text` property because `SelectedItem` is an `object`. We don't know what it is; I'm just going by what OP is using.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Check out my edit mate, in the question. WinForm's ListBox. Var would be better. I am just perplexed why DBNull is not validated in the SQL side...

Comment: @bonCodigo I think my answer will solve your problem, set the `CommandText` appropriately, figure out what `lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem` is (I think you want to cast it to a `string`) and `AddWithValue("@Type", ...` instead of `AddWithValue("@SelectedItem", ...`

Comment: Let me check if C# editor will handle the String casting when the listbox is nul... I hope it's , we are in 2014... using 4.0 though.

Comment: Yes, we are in 2014. It will handle it just fine. `var selectedItem = (string) lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem;` should work assuming `SelectedItem` is only ever `string`s or `null`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do so. `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem.ToString()))` The huge NullReferenceException...boom!

Comment: That's not a cast. See my edit. If `SelectedItem` is going to be something other than `string` or `null` then `var selectedItem = lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem != null ? lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem.ToString() : null`

Answer (score 2):

With the edit, you should be able to replace the last line with:

```
AND (@Type IS NULL OR TT.[_TYPE] = @Type)
```

far clearer, although frankly it doesn't make for great query cache plan usage or optimization; it would still, IMO, be better to just compose the correct SQL.

As for passing in the value:

```
object value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem)
       ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem;
// ...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type", value);
```